# Having difficulty in Prune and Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pruning

[image]

I do understand Input until step 4 (If my understanding is correct) but step 5 is a bit confusing because I don't know what should I put in |S<sub>1</sub>| + |S<sub>2</sub>| ≥ k -- I'm not even sure if it's an absolute value or what. I don't get the iterations too. Uhmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after step 4:

- S1 contains element smaller than p
- S2 contains several occurences of p and only p's
- S3 contains element greater than p

Therefore

- if `|S1| > k` then it contains the k-th element of S
- else if `|S1| + |S2| > k` then S2 contains the k-th element of S which is therefore p
- else the k-th element of S in in S3. So searching the k-th element of s is the same as searching the `(k-|S1|-|S2|)` element of S3. Therefore you restart (ie iterate) the same algorithm with `S = S3` and `k=k-|S1|-|S2|`.

Hope this help.

Comment: What should I exactly put in |S1| + |S2| ? (is that an absolute value?)

Comment: ``|S1|`` is the size of the S1. So ``|S1|`` is the number of elements of S smaller than p, ``|S2|`` the number of elements of S equal to p...

Comment: So that has nothing to do with those parallel lines? Another thing sir, Iterations here is vague to me. When do I iterate?

Comment: See my new explanation.

Comment: I see.. Thank you sir. I think I get that now :)